How to map .net core 8 service configuration file with Azure DevOps variable group while creating nuget package
In my application there are total 35 gRPC service and as par the requirement we need to create nuget package for every service and dependent C# libraries and uploaded it to Azure artifacts feed. But the problem is, we have total 6 environments and for each environment some or other configuration parameters are different. Top of the that each gRPC service dependent on other C# libraries and has cross service reference.
Now the challenge i am facing

How to do I create nuget package, reading azure devops variable group and map with application configuration file

Example:
 "ConnectionStrings": {
    "ConnectionString": "#{MasterDatabaseConnectionString}#",    
  }


MasterDatabaseConnectionString value stored in Azure DevOps one of the variable group, say staging-build-variable

I cannot create nuget package in YAML file since service has dependency with other services. At present i created PowerShell script which will run in local machine against the solution, resolving all service dependency and then upload it to Azure Artifacts feed. But challenge is its unable to resolve the configuration value mentioned in above point.

Please help me or any reference would really help. Struggling from last one week
Tried various options but no luck as of now.


How to do I create nuget package, reading azure devops variable group and map with application configuration file

Based on your requirement, you need to use variables in variable group to update the configuration file.
To meet your requirement, you can try to use the Replace Token task from Replace Tokens Extension.
Here are the steps:
Step1: Keep the value as #{MasterDatabaseConnectionString}# in configuration file. Format: ${...}#
Step2: Add Replace token task before the nuget package create task to set the value.
For example:
- task: replacetokens@6
  inputs:
    root: 'working folder'
    sources: 'appsettings.json'

Step3: Change the variable name in Variable Group to MasterDatabaseConnectionString(same as the value in configuration file).
Then this task will automatically update the value in configuration file based on the variable in variable group.
On the other hand, we can also use PowerShell script to update the value in configuration file based on variables in variable group.
Here is an example:
steps:
- powershell: |
   $pathToJson = "appsettings.json"
   $a = Get-Content $pathToJson | ConvertFrom-Json
   $a.ConnectionStrings.ConnectionString= "$(staging-build-variable)"
   $a | ConvertTo-Json | set-content $pathToJson

